# stuck in partitioning loop installing 12.04 server

Tags: installation

I burned a CD from the iso for Ubuntu 12.04.2 server 64-bit and am working from it.  I have already partitioned my disk.

I selected partition 1 (1GiB) as /boot, ext2, bootable and partition 11 (32GiB) as /, ext4.  When I request the next step, "install base system", it just takes me back to the partition-selection screen. What does it want?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Selecting a partition with mount point `/` as ext4 and swap if necessary will be enough. I think you should not create `/boot` partition.

Comment: I thought EFI size and said 1 GiB not enough, but you are right.

Comment: :) (removed my earlier comments)

Comment: I tried it without the /boot partition, just to see what would happen.  Actually, you should be able to have numerous partitions if you want (/boot, /home, /var,...).  Also, I had a swap partition, but I forgot to mention it.  Anyway, the result was the same.  Can't get past the partitioning screen to the 'install basic system' action.  Ideas, anyone?  (Debian beckons....)